# How to connect 2 expandproperty data with eachother

Tags: powershell, api, get, odata, invoke-restmethod

In my script I use an `expandproperty` 3 times, this to get to the correct data. In the first expand property I also have to use data. But I cannot add this to the select line.

In `-expandproperty` value I have to use `computerbalance` and in `-expandproperty -secureemployer` I have to use `employeenumber`.

This is my script:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url_budgetid -Method Get -Headers $header_process | Select-Object -ExpandProperty value | Select employee | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Employee | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SecureEmployee
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod ... | ForEach-Object { $_.Value.Employee.SecureEmployee }`

Comment: Need more info. Don’t see computerbalance..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `.dotProperty` way to use properties of objects.
You can accumulate only properties you're interested in into one object using `[PSCustomObject]@{Key1=Value1;Key2=Value2;...}` way.

Here's example data and example of it's simplification to a list of objects.

```
$data = @'
[    {
        computer: {balance : 180, name: "Computer1"},
        employee: {displayName: "Juan Carlos Rodrigez", employeeNumber: "Emp123", telephone: "+1234567890"}
    },
    {
        computer: {balance : 220, name: "Computer2"},
        employee: {displayName: "Natalia Marisa Oreiro", employeeNumber: "Emp456", telephone: "+987654321" }
    },
    {
        computer: {balance : 90, name: "Computer3"},
        employee: {displayName: "Don Pedro", employeeNumber: "Emp000", telephone: "+77777777777" }
    }
]
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json
    
$warningLine = 200
$dataSimplified = $data | 
    ForEach-Object { return [PSCustomObject]@{ 
        ComputerBalance = [Int]::Parse($_.computer.balance);  # we can use values 'As Is'
        EmployeeNumber = $_.employee.employeeNumber.ToUpper(); # We can translate or modify falues
        FirstName = $_.employee.displayName.Split(' ')[0]; # We can use them partially
        ShouldWarnLowBalance = $_.computer.balance -le $warningLine } # We can create new properties based on what we whant
        } |
    Where-Object { $_.ShouldWarnLowBalance -eq $true } # We can right then filter output depending on our generated values
        
#> $dataSimplified
#
#ComputerBalance EmployeeNumber FirstName ShouldWarnLowBalance
#--------------- -------------- --------- --------------------
#            180 EMP123         Juan                      True
#             90 EMP000         Don                       True
```

---

I'm using powershell for over 5 years and never used `-ExpandProperty` syntax.

Comment: filimonic, thanx for your answer, iam almost there but the results i get are not the same as yours. My results are like this:

EmployeeNumber                                  computerBalance                       
--------------                                  ---------------                       
{A20200626-00, A20200626-01, 100003, 100015...} {$null, $null, 1695,4000, 323,0400...}

The data is next to eachother instead below :(

Comment: It's better is you can export data BEFORE you work with it? and code and upload somewhere. To export data, use Export-CliXML

Comment: filimonic , i can export it, but i want the file to be in a csv format like:
ComputerBalance; EmployeeNumber
180; EMP123
 90; EMP000

is that posible?

Comment: Of course it's possible, but I need to see source data to help you making data in fformat you want

Comment: This is the whole input:

Comment: is this a general approach towards parsing `JSON`?

Comment: `ConvertFrom-Json` is general approach for quite small JSON data.